# Matrix exponential versus Jordan blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Good evening everyone , I need help on this one please :

Let $a$ be a complex number

and let J defined as the matrix containing the blocks of Jordan matrices

Let $M\in M_n\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ defined as:

$M=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}a^{k}J^{k}}{k}$

prove that $exp(M)=I_{n}+aJ$

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the relation between $J$ and $M$? What do you mean by "the matrix containing the blocks of Jordan matrices"? Also, do you have any idea how to approach the problem?

Comment: $J$ is defined as $diag(J_r_{1},......,J_r_{s})$ where the $J_r_{i}$  's are the block of Jordan , I tried to calculate the powers of the block of jordan I think it doesn't help what's your idea ?

Comment: You mean the Jordan blocks of the Jordan form of $M$?

Comment: no the jordan block having 0's in the diagonal and 1's in the upper diagonal

Comment: This is too hard , it's killing me

Comment: @levap He means that $J$ is in Jordan canonical form

Comment: Note: some answers that are applicable to this post are [written here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3511229/81360)

Answer (score 2):

A few approaches, sketched:

Note that 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}x^k
$$
is the MacLaurin series for $\ln(1+x)$.  In particular: whenever the series converges (when $|x|<1$), $f(x) = \ln(1+x)$ for any scalar $x$.  Our matrix $M$ is given by $M = f(aJ)$.

It's easy to see that whenever $J$ is diagonalizable (and $a$ is sufficiently small), $\exp(J) = \exp(\ln(I + aJ)) = I + aJ$.  From there, an easy approach is to simply state that this applies to all matrices, since the functions involved are continuous and the diagonalizable matrices are dense.

Alternatively, it suffices to note the composition of power series is another power series, and that with $g(x) = \sum \frac{x^n}{n!} = \exp(x)$.  We find that $g(f(x)) = 1 + x$ in the scalar case, which means the same applies in the matrix case.

However, it is unlikely (given the form of the question) that they're looking for an argument from continuity, or via power series alone.  So, here's a direct proof in the case of a single Jordan block.  In particular, take $J$ to be the $n \times n$ matrix
$$
J = \pmatrix{\lambda&1\\&\lambda&\ddots\\&&\ddots\\&&&&1\\&&&&\lambda}
$$
We compute
$$
M = f(aJ) = \pmatrix{f(a\lambda)&\frac 1{1!}f'(a\lambda)&\frac 1{2!}f''(a\lambda)&\cdots\\
& f(a\lambda)&\frac{1}{1!}f'(a\lambda)&\frac 1{2!}f''(a\lambda)\\
&&\ddots}
$$
as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Matrix_functions).  Not sure where one would go from there.

Comment: Shouldn't the MacLaurin series start the summation with index $i=1$?

Comment: @PaulWintz Do I indicate otherwise?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped; I meant to ask if the index should start at $i=0$, but I see now that $\ln(1+0)=0$, so the $i=0$ term is zero.