# Logarithm of a Jordan block

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, logarithms, matrix-calculus, jordan-normal-form

I don't understand how to find a logarithm of Jordan block. Wikipedia says, that we can use Mercator series, but I don't know why it works for matrices - I know only the proof for real numbers. In some other books I've only found explanation on the level "by contruction we have that $ e^B=A $" and the elements of matrix $ B $. Can anybody explain formally how to find this logarithm?

**Edit**. By finding the logarithm I mean not just deriving the formula for it, but rigorous proof that this formula is correct. If $ A $ is a Jordan block of the form $ \lambda I + N $, where $ N $ is nilpotent and $ I $ is identity matrix, I know that

$$ B=\log{A}=I\log{\lambda}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j\lambda^j}N^j. $$

Unfortunately, I don't understand how to prove that $ e^B=A. $ I tried to do it by the definition of exponential, but I wasn't successful.

Comment: "I've only found explanation on the level 'by contruction we have that $ e^B=A $ and the description of matrix $ B $'": why is such an explanation not sufficient? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, by description I've meant matrix elements. I don't understand why what I see is the logarithm, because I can't calculate the exponent of any matrix.

Answer (score 1):

A Jordan block is in the form $A=\lambda I_n+J$ where $J$ is the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $n$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$.

When $\lambda\notin (-\infty,0]$, the principal logarithm of $A=\lambda(I+u J)$ (where $u=\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$) is

$\log(A)=\log(\lambda)I+uJ-\dfrac{1}{2}(uJ)^2+\dfrac{1}{3}(uJ)^3+\cdots$

with the definition: $\log(\lambda)=\log(r)+i\theta$ when $\lambda=r\exp(i\theta), \theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$.

Note that the above sum is finite because $J^n=0$ and that we use the standard series of $\log(1+v)$ when $|v|<1$.

EDIT.

Assume that, on the complex numbers,  $f(y)=\sum_i a_iy^i,|y|<u$ and $y=g(x)=\sum_{j\geq 1} b_jx^j,|x|<v$ is s.t. $b_1\not= 0$ and for every $|x|<v$, one has $|g(x)|<u$. Let $\phi_k(x)=\tau_k(\sum_{i=0}^k a_i(\sum_{j=1}^k b_jx^j)^i)$ where $\tau_k$ keeps only the monomials of degree $\leq k$..

Then $(f\circ g)(x)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\phi_k(x)$ (uniformly locally convergent series with radius $\geq v$).

One has a similar result for the matrices (same proof. -that is your business- the key being $||A^p||\leq ||A||^p$): Let $f(B)=\sum_i a_iB^i$ and $B=g(A)=\sum_{j\geq 1} b_jA^j$;

$(f\circ g)(A)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\phi_k(A)$ for $||A||<u$ and even for $\rho(A)=\max((|\lambda_i|)_i<u$.

Now, if $(f\circ g)(x)=x$, then $A=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\phi_k(A)$.

In particular, if $A=uJ$, then $uJ=\phi_{n-1}(uJ)$.

Comment: Although the question ended on "Can anybody explain formally how to find this logarithm", it seems that the primary thrust of the question is "how do we know (given some expression for the logarithm) that we really have $\exp(\ln(A)) = A$"?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question so that it would be clear what exactly do I want to proof.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  You are right but your method is too complicated for a  beginner. I prefer i) to do a formal reasoning giving an explicit form $\phi$ of $\log(A)$ and ii) to prove that $\exp(\phi)=A$. The second part  comes from the composition of two converging complex series; mutatis mutandis, we can apply the same reasoning to the series of matrices. So we know that we can formally obtain a particular solution, which reassures students. At least, it's my opinion...

Comment: @loupblanc I was thinking for a while about that approach, but I got hung up on the fact that we're composing two infinite Taylor series. So for instance, if $S_n$ denotes the partial sums for the log series, I can't argue that $\exp(S_n) \to \exp(S)$ unless either have some sort of formula for $\exp(S_n)$ or make an argument by continuity

Comment: It's not clear to me at all why Taylor theorem is applicable in this case.

Comment: You're missing parentheses around the matrix series following the $\log(\lambda)$ term.

Comment: @greg I think that it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

An informal "proof":

For any two polynomials $p(x),q(x)$, the composition $p\circ q$ is another polynomial.  For instance:
$$
p(x) = 1 + x^2, \quad q(x) = x - x^3\\
p(q(x)) = 1 + (x - x^3)^2 = 1 + x^2 - 2x^4 + x^6.
$$
The same is true for polynomials on matrices.  For instance,
$$
p(X) = I + X^2, \quad q(X) = X - X^3\\
p(q(X)) = I + (X - X^3)^2 = I + X^2 - 2X^4 + X^6.
$$
Composing "matrix polynomials" in this way always gives you the same result as composing scalar polynomials.

Likewise, we can consider the power series, noting that the composition of two power series is another power series.
$$
p(x) = \exp(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}, \quad
q(x) = \log(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty -\frac{(1-x)^k}{k},\\
p(q(x)) = x.
$$
Because $\exp(\log(x)) = x$ applies for scalar power series, it must be the case that for any matrix $A$, we have $p(q(A)) = A$ (as long as $q(A)$ is defined).  That is, $\exp(\log(A)) = A$, where $\log$ was defined by the Mercator series.

---

If I have understood your question correctly, the primary concern is this: given some expression for the logarithm $\log(A)$ of a matrix $A$, how do we know that this matrix will really satisfy $\exp(\log(A)) = A$, where $\exp$ is the matrix-exponential?

One argument goes as follows.

1. Show that $\exp(\log(A)) = A$ holds whenever $A$ is diagonalizable
2. Show that the functions $X \mapsto \exp(X)$, $X \mapsto \log(X)$ are continuous (since it is the uniform limit of continuous functions over any closed and bounded subset of its domain)
3. Show that for any non-diagonalizable matrix $A$ (a Jordan block for instance), there exist a sequence of diagonalizable matrices $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $A_n \to A$
4. By continuity, 
   $$
   A = \lim_{n \to \infty}A_n =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp(\log(A_n)) = \exp(\log(A))
   $$
   as desired.

Comment: Thank you for an interesting approach, but it looks way too complicated for such a problem. Basically what I'm asking for is an explanation how to perform some calculation.

Comment: You say that here, but in your question you now say that you already have such a procedure and also say "I mean not just deriving the formula for it, but rigorous proof that this formula is correct"; so apparently that is not what you are asking for.

Comment: Well, in some cases calculation is a rigorous proof.

Comment: In **some cases**, sure. It sounds like what you are trying to say, then, is that you're specifically looking for a proof that uses explicit calculation.

Comment: I'm looking for a proof which I would completely understand. I tend to think that I can understand the proof that uses explicit calculation, but I'm not sure that I can understand the proof that uses, say, continuity of some functions on matrices, because I've never encountered them yet.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: First of all, am I right that 'your' $ \log(x) $ converges for the same reason as $ \exp(x) $? (that is, matrices form Banach space and partial sums form a Cauchy sequence?) I can believe in construction of power series of matrices, after all, that's probably just a limit in the category of rings/modules. What I find unsatisfying here is why some relation in real numbers should pass to matrices?

Comment: So "continuity of some functions on matrices" is not okay, but "limit in the category of ring/modules" is?  Very strange criteria you have.  At any rate: yes, ultimately that is one justification of convergence, but you could get around that by sticking to the weaker statement that the identity holds whenever the series happens to converge.  As for your second point: one way to see it is to note that a composition of polynomials or power series (whatever the functions' argument) ultimately comes down to a manipulation of the sequence of coefficients.

Comment: Also, rather than appealing to some unfamiliar topology, you could argue that the absolute value of the matrix entries of the $k$th term in the sum must fall below $cr^k$ for some constant $c$, where $r$ is the spectral radius of $A - I$.

Comment: I would probably believe it if product of matrices was a commutative operation, but it's not. So it's not clear why it is correct, to be honest

Comment: @Kumquat but you're only multiplying the powers of a particular matrix.  By the associativity of matrix multiplication, we have $A^j A^k = A^k A^j = A^{j + k}$.

Comment: Ok, I agree with that. Not a rigorous proof, of course, but it clears something up